# How to create a dynamic filtered web list based on database values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have setup a database of transportation types, and have entered various metadata about those  types into a web based database (MySQL).  The types and classification values of my data will be dynamic so I don't want to hard-code too much.

I would like to create a web based filter pane where the various attributes of my data are presented for the user to apply various filters to the data, once the various filter attributes have been selected I would like to execute a query to the database and return the resulting records in a grid on the page...

See the example below:

[image]

In the example, i would like to associate images to some of the attribute types in the database So that when the user clicks on the image, the grid is updated with the relevant database information.

I would like to use PHP, ajax and Html to do this... however I would like to know if there are any frameworks and specific components that I can use to make this easy (such as jQuery or MooTools)

This is all new to me, and any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, sorry, this is way too broad for a Stack Overflow question. Do you have *specific* questions about how to do something?

Comment: Yes, jQuery would really help, especially when dealing with the AJAX requests. As @Pekka웃 noted, though, your question is rather broad.

Comment: Thanks for the gentile response. yes I guess this is a little generic.  I am trying to find out what ajax library set i should put my effort into... to make this easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is close to the "Faceted Search". Please google for the term, you will get a lot of information.

You can use Solr or Lucene to implement the faceted search.

Comment: Thanks... that is precisely what i was looking for!.... as seen in this example http://well-formed-data.net/experiments/elastic_lists/